# Regular expression for changing links in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, replace

I'm in the process of moving my [Dreamweaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver)-based website to a CMS, and I would like to replace site-wide the following kind of links:

```
a href="http://www.domain.com/category/item ### title.html" (where ### is a number)
```

to

```
a href="http://www.domain.com/category/item###"
```

What is the correct regular expression I should use in the find and replace built-in engine?

Answer (score 0):

I propose

```
'(http://www.domain.com/category/item) *(\d+).+?\.html'
```

as RE chain

and to substitute the entire match with $1 + $2